# With the bash shell, how can a cut column be output multiple times

Tags: bash, shell

What is the right way to cut columns and print some of them multiple times in the output:

```
cut -d " " -f1,3,3,4 in > out
```

does not work.

Answer (score 6):

```
awk '{print $1" "$3" "$3" "$4}' in > out
```

Comment: @Hans: Please consider accepting this answer then. And possible answers to your previous questions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Bash

```
OLDIFS="$IFS"
while read -r line
do
  set -- $line
  echo "$1 $3 $3 $5"
done <file
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

Comment: hey, that's a pretty neat way to use `set`. +1